# Copying files from multiple directories using a loop

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a set of single files `basename.file`, in multiple directories `basename_dir`. I want to copy all the `.file` files into a single directory. I have created a `.txt` containing all basenames. I want to use a for do loop to do this, but keep getting an error

This is what I am using:

```
for i in `basenames.txt`; do cd ${i}_dir; cp ${i}.file ../files; done
```

I just keep getting errors

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash) about looping through the file content.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
for i in `basenames.txt`; do ...
```

attempts to *execute* `basenames.txt` and loop over the resulting (whitespace split) tokens.

Although you *could* have written `` for i in `cat basenames.txt`; do ... `` it's not recommended - better to use a `while read` loop.

As well, there doesn't appear to be any value in `cd`ing to the directory (and you forgot to `cd` back each time). So:

```
while read -r i; do
  cp "${i}_dir/${i}.file" files/
done < basenames.txt
```

The trailing `/` on `files/` ensures that the target is treated as a directory.